# MDM Server Hidden

Tags: mdm

We built an MDM server a few years ago using a mac mini and OSX server.  This system is managing about 200 iPads.  We used the system yesterday and everything worked fine.  Today when logging into the profile manager the system gave us an error that said our password or username was not correct.

We logged into the server and saw that the user that had all of the profiles associated with it seems to have been deleted.  We could log into the profile manager using another user none of the profiles are there however you can see the background processes that the server is pushing.

None of the iPads have lost the applications install using the MDM so we feel that the user is somehow hidden?

Has anyone ever run into anything similar?

Comment: Did you upgrade your profile manager? How is the server built in general?